# How do I adjust the width of a series in an Excel chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2011

Here is a picture of my current chart:

[image: My Plumber Chart]

I've tried to modify the scale to get the series' (the column) to be thicker. Ideally, I'd like the columns to be closer together too. I've double-clicked on the `Horizontal Axis` to bring up the options box to modify the scale, but this doesn't get me what I want.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the Gap Width under Series Properties?

Comment: Yes. That's with the Gap Width at 0. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the Horizontal axis type to be 'Text' instead of 'Automatic' or 'Date'. This leads to some mislabeling in the data labels, but you just need to adjust the data labels so that it looks correct (for whatever usage you intend).